# Typeahead not working in bootstrap tags

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-bootstrap-2, yii2, bootstrap-tags-input

My bootstrap tag field is not working with typehead.My bootstrap version is 2.3 and i am working in yii2 framework.

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" id="tags"
         value="<?php echo   $model->tags;?>"/>
```

Script:

```
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];
  $('input[type=text][id="tags"]').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
  source: function(query) {
  return colors;
  }
  }
  });
```

ERROR

```
   TypeError: text is undefined

   matcher()bootst...nput.js (line 278)
   text = undefined
    transition()bootstrap.min.js (line 6)
    a = undefined
    f()jquery.min.js (line 2)
    a = function()
    b = function()
    c = false
    transition()bootstrap.min.js (line 6)
    b = undefined
    transition()bootstrap.min.js (line 6)
    a = Object { originalEvent=Event keyup, type="keyup", timeStamp=16416032, more...}
    (?)()analyse?id=3 (line 2)
    H()jquery.min.js (line 3)
    c = Object { originalEvent=Event keyup, type="keyup", timeStamp=16416032, more...}
    H()jquery.min.js (line 3)
    a = keyup charCode=0, keyCode=82

    return (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle which reproduce the error?

Comment: try upgrade to boostrap 3

Comment: I'll bet you have `data-role="tagsinput"` on your `<input>`, remove this and your code is fine, see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4Lj77/** (bootstrap 2.3.x and tags input for 2.x)